# Accessing Elements and Attributes from a Live Feed XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, http-live-streaming, android-livedata

I am trying to access the time until the next bus arrives for a Live Feed bus transit system in Asheville NC at the given bus stop but I keep returning two console errors:
"time is not defined" 
and 
"Cannot read property of geElementsbyTagName of undefined"

You can use "470" as an exam `stopID` to see the XML file.

I have made sure the right stop ID is being added although I am not sure I am adding the ID correctly onto the URL.
If the element is nested in another, is that an issue?

```
var feedURL = "http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=predictions&a=art&stopId="+stopID;
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        attribute(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", feedURL, true);
xhttp.send();

function attribute(feedURL){
    var y; 
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var time = "";
    y = xmlDoc.getElementsbyTagName('prediction');
    time = x.getAttribute('minutes');
}
console.log(time);
```

I am expecting the number of minutes given until the bus arrives at a given stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to log the value of variable `time` outside of the function you've defined it in. You could change your code to this and that should work:

```
function attribute(feedURL){
    var y; 
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var time = "";
    y = xmlDoc.getElementsbyTagName('prediction');
    time = x.getAttribute('minutes');

    console.log(time);
}
```

Comment: That works for the time issue but the getElementsbyTagName are still undefined. Not sure why!

Comment: I'd like to help with that however I don't see where variable `xml` is defined. The actual error is saying `xmlDoc` is null so you can't call `getElementsByTagName` on it. I can't tell you why `xmlDoc` is null without knowing where `xml` is coming from. It must be that `xml.responseXML` is null because it is defined within a different scope (and so that function cannot see it unless it is passed as a parameter or if it is defined in a more global scope.)